# Can't use ArrayList methods in main

Tags: java, class, arraylist, undefined

I am trying to write a simulation for solitaire game. I wrote my classes and functions. I will try to hold my card objects in ArrayLists. However in the main I can't use the methods of ArrayList. I think I created PileOfCards objects in ArrayList type in Representation class. Because in PileOfCards class, in the constructor I created an ArrayList. So I wanted to make that every time we created an object from PileOfCards class its type is ArrayList. I mean I want to use ArrayList methods on my PileOfCards objects. But in my main I got an error "The method size() is undefined for the type PileOfCards" and for the get(3). I believe PileOfCards objects are ArrayList type. Why I have got an error like this. Any help will be appreciated.

```
// MY CARD CLASS
public class Card 
{

/* I assigned variables to numbers because I can use them later easily.
 * And they can not be changed
 */
public final static int red     = 0;
public final static int black    = 1;

public final static int heart = 0;
public final static int spade = 1;
public final static int diamond = 2;
public final static int club = 3;

public final static int ace     = 0;
public final static int jack    = 10;
public final static int queen    = 11;
public final static int king    = 12;

public static String values[] = {"A" , "2" , "3" , "4" , "5" , "6" , "7",
                                "8" , "9" , "10" , "J" , "Q" , "K"};   

private int value;
private int suit;
boolean faceUp;

// Create card object with parameters.
Card(int value_in, int suit_in, boolean face_type)
{

    value = value_in;
    suit = suit_in;
    faceUp = face_type;
}

// Make the card face up
public void faceUp()
{
    faceUp = true;
}

// Make the card face down
public void faceDown()
{
    faceUp = false;
}

// return card is face up or face down
public final boolean cardStatus()
{
    return faceUp;
}

// return the value of the card
public final int cardValue()
{
    return value;
}

// return the suit of the card
public final int cardSuit()
{
    return suit;
}

// return the color of the card
public final int color()
{
    if(cardSuit()==heart || cardSuit()==diamond)
    {
        return red;
    }
    else
    {
        return black;
    }
}

public String toString() {
    return ("Card Suit: "+this.cardSuit()+
            " Card Value: "+ this.cardValue() +
            " Card Status: "+ this.cardStatus() +
            " Color : " + this.color());
   }
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// MY PILEOFCARDS CLASS
import java.util.*;

public class PileOfCards 
{
/* I created pile as ArrayList because the elements of the list will change.
 * So using ArrayList is more useful and easier.
 */
public ArrayList<Card> pile;

//create an empty pile
PileOfCards()
{

    // Create pile with card objects
    this.pile = new ArrayList<Card>();
}

//create a deck with 52 cards
public void makeDeck()
{

    for (int a=0; a<=3; a++)
    {
        for (int b=0; b<=12; b++)
        {
            pile.add(new Card(a, b, false)); 
        }
    }

}

// shuffling the cards
public void shuffle()
{

    Collections.shuffle(this.pile);
}

// get the top card and remove that. I think the first element of the list as top card
public Card takeTopCard()
{

    if(pile.isEmpty()) 
    {
        return null; 
    }
    else 
    {    
        Card top = pile.get(0);
        pile.remove(0);
        return top;
    }
}

// add a specific card to the pile
public void addCardToPile(Card c)
{

    pile.add(c);
}

// determines the pile can take card
public boolean canTakeSuit (Card aCard)  
{   if (pile.isEmpty())
        return aCard.cardValue() == 0;
    Card topCard = pile.get(0);
    return (aCard.cardSuit() == topCard.cardSuit()) &&
        (aCard.cardValue() == 1 + topCard.cardValue());
}


public boolean canTakeValue (Card aCard) 
{   if (pile.isEmpty())
        return aCard.cardValue() == 12;
    Card topCard = pile.get(0);
    return (aCard.color() != topCard.color()) &&
           (aCard.cardValue() == topCard.cardValue() - 1);
}

public void selectSuit () 
{   if (pile.isEmpty())
        return;

    // if face down flip the card
    Card topCard = pile.get(0);
    if ( topCard.cardStatus() != true) 
    {   
        topCard.faceUp();
    }

    pile.remove(0);

    if(canTakeSuit(topCard))
    {
        pile.add(topCard);
    }
    else
    {
    addCardToPile(topCard);
    }
}

public void selectValue () 
{   if (pile.isEmpty())
        return;

    // if face down flip the card
    Card topCard = pile.get(0);
    if ( topCard.cardStatus() != true) 
    {   
        topCard.faceUp();
    }

    pile.remove(0);

    if(canTakeValue(topCard))
    {
        pile.add(topCard);
    }
    else
    {
    addCardToPile(topCard);
    }
}
}
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MY REPRESENTATION CLASS
public class Representation
{

// create the main pile. we will deal the cards from here
static PileOfCards mainPile = new PileOfCards();

// create a pile for opening cards. This pile can hold only one card.
static PileOfCards oneCardPile = new PileOfCards();

// create a pile that holds the cards in one suit from ace to king
static PileOfCards oneSuitPile1 = new PileOfCards();

// create a pile that holds the cards in one suit from ace to king
static PileOfCards oneSuitPile2 = new PileOfCards();

// create a pile that holds the cards in one suit from ace to king
static PileOfCards oneSuitPile3 = new PileOfCards();

// create a pile that holds the cards in one suit from ace to king
static PileOfCards oneSuitPile4 = new PileOfCards();

// create the pile that holds one card at the beginning - max. 13 cards
static PileOfCards firstPile = new PileOfCards();

// create the pile that holds 2 cards at the beginning - max. 13 cards
static PileOfCards secondPile = new PileOfCards();

// create the pile that holds 3 cards at the beginning - max. 13 cards
static PileOfCards thirdPile = new PileOfCards();

// create the pile that holds 4 cards at the beginning - max. 13 cards
static PileOfCards fourthPile = new PileOfCards();

// create the pile that holds 5 cards at the beginning - max. 13 cards
static PileOfCards fifthPile = new PileOfCards();

// create the pile that holds 6 cards at the beginning - max. 13 cards
static PileOfCards sixthPile = new PileOfCards();

// create the pile that holds 7 cards at the beginning - max. 13 cards
static PileOfCards seventhPile = new PileOfCards();
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MY DEMO CLASS
import java.util.*;

public class Demo
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Representation.mainPile.makeDeck();
    for(int i=0; i<Representation.mainPile.size(); i++)
    System.out.println(Representation.mainPile.get(i));
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PileOfCards` class is not an `ArrayList` itself, it only has a property of that type.

Use `Representation.mainPile.pile.size()` instead of just `Representation.mainPile.size()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a method size in the class `PileOfCards` which will return the size of the arrayList :

```
public int size(){
   return pile.size();
}
```

And to get the card :

```
public Card get(int index){
   return pile.get(index);
}
```

> Didn't I create my PileOfCards object as an arraylist?

No you didn't, `PileOfCards` is a class that can constructs objects of type `PileOfCards` which have an attribute that is an `arrayList`.

Comment: I know but why I can't use the method of arraylist? Also I will use lots of methods of arraylist later in my code. Didn't I create my PileOfCards object as an arraylist?

Comment: You would have to use `extends ArrayList<Card>` or `implements List<Card>`